# Remove Filter When Exposed Filter is Selected

Tags: views

Currently, I'm working on an events view in Drupal 8 which needs to only show events that are on or after the current date (now() filter). This view also has an exposed date range filter that allows user's to select a start date and end date. The start date can be from before the current date.

The problem is that the now() filter isn't letting user's see anything before the current date. How can I remove the now() filter when a user enters a start date so they see the list of all the events in the date range they've selected?

Comment: I'd remove the filter and set a default value for the exposed filters instead

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, @Hudri
Do you know of a way to programmatically remove the default value after the page loads? So the user isn't faced with an input field that reads "now"?

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by combining two "Authored on" Filters, one regular and the other one Exposed with the `OR` Operator working between them/groups of Filters.

Add the regular "Authored on" Filter **Is less than or equal to** `now`.

Add another "Authored on" Filter and Expose it with your preferred settings, how you want your visitors to use it, don't enter a default value.

Then under `Add` dropdown choose `And/Or Rearrange`, Create a new filter group. move the Exposed "Authored on" to it, and choose the `OR` between the groups, while keeping `AND` within groups.

Recreate any Filters you might need in the second group.

That's it!

Be very careful of your entire Filters configuration. If you have Exposed filters in the first group too, they will not be able to be applied at the same time (because OR), which may be confusing to users...